# log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger

Tags: java, log4j

i try to use second log file with my default log file in servlet 
i have this log4j.xml configuration .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" ERROR="false">


    <appender name="FILE_error" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender"> 
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>   
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10240KB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />    
        <param name="File" value="logs/engine.log"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %t %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n "/>
        </layout>
    </appender>


     <appender name="CONSOLE_error" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">           
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %t %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n "/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <category name="errorLogger" additivity="false">
        <priority value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_error"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_error"/>
    </category>



    <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender"> 
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>   
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10240KB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />    
        <param name="File" value="logs/error_info.log"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %t %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n "/>
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">           
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %t %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n "/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <category name="com.foo" additivity="false">
        <priority value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </category>

    <category name="org.apache" additivity="false">
        <priority value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </category>

     <root>
        <priority value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_error"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_error"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

now in the servlet i set the logger like this :

```
public class PaymentConfirmation extends HttpServlet implements Constants{
    private static final Logger errorLog= Logger.getLogger("errorLogger");
```

but when running :
errorLog.debug("Starting app");
i got :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (errorLogger).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

log4j and log4j.xml are in class path
what do i do wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error. Can you please try running your java program with -Dlog4j.debug java option. It will give some insight into what is failing and you would be able to resolve that then.